# Is there a syntax that can open a FORM1 in the background and populate 3 to 4 controls of same FORM1 with the same data as another open FORM2?

Tags: ms-access-2016, vba7

I have a database with three forms among others.
FORM1 has 4 comboboxes that are partly used to populate FORM2. (Comboboxes A, B, C, D)
Wnen FORM2 is opened and entries are made, saved and closed.
I want users to be able to open FORM3 which has 3 identical Comboboxes (Comboboxes A,B,D) as FORM1 to use those controls to open FORM1 in the BACKGROUND (Not VISIBLE) and FORM2 VISIBLE.

Thanks in advance for your help...

I currently used the same vba for the command buttons On click event of FORM1 and FORM3 since they both open the same FORM2. Unforyunately, when FORM2 opens with the click event of FORM3 it is blank because it expects to see the controls of FORM1.

Dim stDocName As String

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.echo False

stDocName = "frm_FORM2"
DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName, acNormal, acEdit

DoCmd.SetWarnings True
DoCmd.echo True

End Sub